# trying to enable mod_status but I get "Syntax error..."

Tags: apache

I am trying to enable mod_status on my server. I have mod_status.so module installed and the relevant part of my .conf file is (I plan to restrict access to only my IP once I get it running):

```
LoadModule status_module     modules/mod_status.so
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

I restart apache and get an error: "Syntax error on line 4 of /path/to/httpd.conf"...which points to the line:

```
Order Allow,Deny
```

I've tried all combinations of lowercase, uppercase and a space between the comma and "Deny". What am I doing wrong?
I am using Apache 2.2.25 (and I do have 2 virtualhosts)

Thanks!

Comment: maybe it needs `Deny` also in this case, but only `Allow` specified

Comment: is this set at the top of your httpd.conf? maybe it's not the right place, maybe all modules aren't loaded yet.

Comment: @Deadooshka: I've also tried adding the Deny from all with no luck.

Comment: @regilero: I load all my modules at the top, including mod_status. The <Location /server-status> part is at the bottom of the .conf file.

Comment: I got no errors with copy/paste, so this code seems valid.

Comment: Are you sure this is on line 4 of httpd.conf?

Comment: @regilero: it is actually on like line 95 or so of my code....I just wanted to put a snippet of the file here. The problem occurs on the line "Order Allow,Deny" line of my code....I just changed "95" to "4"....my httpd.conf file runs fine without the /server-status portion.

Comment: Having this same issue... will update if I find a resolution, and would like detail from the OP if you ever found a reason for this.